# Android deep linking issue

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an issue when i try to open `<a href="tohome://print?https://qcblob.blob.core.windows.net/testing/LabelTesting/label_sample2.png">items</a>` this link do not open application.

My manifest file:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="print?" android:scheme="tohome"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Wouldnt the `?` already be a path delimiter, meaning you should just be using `print` as the host?

Comment: i need ? for splitting purpose. Do you think this is a case ?

Comment: In a URI schema, the first ? Is already used to split the host from the parameters - I have not used filters like this myself, but worth a shot?

Comment: going to check right now

Comment: post you're answer pls it was a case

Comment: Woohoo, glad to help :D I am on mobile - will post a properly formatted answer / explanation soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the target link

```
tohome://print?https://qcblob.blob.core.windows.net/testing/LabelTesting/label_sample2.png
```

Then your `host` in this case would simply be `print`.

```
<data android:host="print" android:scheme="tohome"/>
```

A typical [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) will follow the following format

> scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]

In this format, the `?` character will be the delimiter that separates the host, from the actual query string.